Remove shipping fees from the total commission value due to the seller
How to disable catulaI'm using the dokan plugin and have a problem: When the order is in "completed" status, the total admin commission = total set commission + with shipping amount. I changed in dokan's settings the person responsible for shipping fees is admin. Please guide me to remove shipping f
Tôi đã thử thay đổi code trong tệp dokan/include/commission.php nhưng không thành công.
